# Optimize the retrieval of a small number of records from database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, performance

I'm running the following query:

```
User.where("number > ?", 5).order(&:age).first(20)
```

I noticed that the speed of the query was about the same whether I replaced "first(20)" with "first(200)" or even just "first". This seems to imply that all records are retrieved by the server, no matter how many records I actually want in the array. Are there any ways to possibly expedite this process?

Comment: Both `order` and `first` will use limit and create the same sql.  You can look at the query in a log or in the console and then take the sql to a db console to `explain` it to examine index usage.  It may be just as fast at 20 as 200 because it's not a significant difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance may well be similar, because in general the database is going to have to identify all of the rows that match the conditions, then order them all, then read the first n rows from the sorted set. If n is 200 then obviously it will have to return more rows to the application, but the primary driver on *database* performance is probably not the quantity of rows returned but the quantity of rows to be ordered.

As others state:

```
User.where("number > ?", 5).order(:age).limit(20)
```

... or to get those with the highest age ...

```
User.where("number > ?", 5).order(:age => :desc).limit(20)
```

(Rails 4 syntax)

There are occasions when the database can use an index to provide the sort order, in which case you'd likely see a much larger performance difference between 20 or 200 rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform the query with `limit`:

```
User.where("number > ?", 5).order(:age).limit(20)
```

Check this [Rails Guides article](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#limit-and-offset) for more examples.

Good luck!

Comment: yes.. I know. That's why I asked. Please remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use limit since you're ordering the results:

```
User.where("number > ?", 5).order('age desc').limit(20)
```

Comment: `order` dosent take `proc` as argument.

Comment: good call. i just pasted in the code from the example and swapped out first for limit. Updated code